# iPhone: deselectRowAtIndexPath after reload

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have 2 views in my navigation stack `View1` and `View2`. `View1` is a `tableView`. So what I trying to do is to `deselectRow when I come back from`View2`to`View1`. That works fine if just to do like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:myIP animated:NO];
```

}

But also I need to reload that row. But if to call `reload`, `deselect` is not working :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

     NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
     [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:myIP animated:NO];
     [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myIP] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];   
}
```

I also tried to `select` row and `deselect` it, that works, but the problem is that I open View1 at the first time or from another View, I see deselect animation

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myIP] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:myIP animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:myIP animated:NO];

}
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Could you not deselect the row in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** (for view1) before you jump to your new view?  That way you don't have to worry about deselecting it upon return. That's what I'd usually do.

Comment: (Updated my answer to use the selection method for a table row)

Comment: This is usually the way to do this. As Simon said just add [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row]; to the end of your didSelectRowAtIndexPath tableView delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Normally while moving from one view to other view,if first view is table view then in table view delagate source there will be method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath:" under this method we will call the classes and in calling there are two types
1.Using PresentModalViewController
                    -it will be like navigationand using back button first view can be called.
2.Using PushViewController
                    -it will be just moving to next view and for coming back to same view we  must again add an IBACTION button and use dismiss modal viewcontroller.

This is the methods for movement betwwen two views.....

Answer (score 0):

I agree that deselecting the row before moving to the next view sounds like your best option, however, I have found that it is better to deselect the row in the `viewDidDisappear` method, as so:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSIndexPath *selected = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if ( selected ) [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selected animated:NO];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

The last two lines of that code would help if you are changing any formatting in the cells when they are selected, such as changing the row height.  If the formatting remains the same for selected/unselected rows, you can disregard those two lines.